# Bash script "fi lines not found"

Tags: linux, bash

This is my first bash script ever, essentially it just shuts off my second monitor. But I've been having problems with it, as it keeps giving me errors when I run it.

```
#!/bin/bash


read -p "Do you want the 2nd monitor on or off? " ON_OFF

if [$ON_OFF == on]; then
xrandr --output DVI-I-3 --auto --right-of DVI-I-0
echo "done"
fi

if [$ON_OFF == off]; then
xrandr --output DVI-I-3 --off   
echo "done"
fi
```

When I run it I get

```
monitor_control.sh: 11: [[off: not found
monitor_control.sh: 16: [[off: not found
```

Can anybody explain to me why it's not working?

Comment: From the error you posted, it looks like you tried this using bash's `[[` conditional expression syntax as well. The same answers regarding spacing apply to that syntax as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add space around `[` and `]`, as they are separate commands in bash.

Moreover, either quotes need to be used around parameter expansions, or `[[ ]]` needs to be used instead of `[ ]`.

That is, you can either use:

```
if [[ $ON_OFF = on ]]
```

...or you can use:

```
if [ "$ON_OFF" = on ]
```

Otherwise you will get error if `$ON_OFF` is empty.

Finally, it's better to use `if ... then ... else ... fi`, like:

```
if [[ $ON_OFF = on ]]; then
    xrandr --output DVI-I-3 --auto --right-of DVI-I-0
else
    xrandr --output DVI-I-3 --off   
fi
echo "done."
```

Comment: Actually -- only `=`, not `==`, is allowed for POSIX `[`; the latter is a bash extension, and not compatible with minimal shells... and if you _are_ going to use bash-only extensions, just use `[[`, which results in far fewer headaches in general.

Comment: @Charls, you're right. But we already know that he's using `bash`, not `sh`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#!/bin/bash


echo -n "Do you want the 2nd monitor on or off? "
read ON_OFF;

if [ $ON_OFF == "on" ]; then
  xrandr --output DVI-I-3 --auto --right-of DVI-I-0
  echo "done"
fi

if [ $ON_OFF == "off" ]; then
  xrandr --output DVI-I-3 --off
  echo "done"
fi
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an unexpected operator error                         [: 11: off: unexpected operator
[: 16: off: unexpected operator

Comment: The script is working fine on my slackware `root@*:~# bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(2)-release (i486-slackware-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Did you copy/paste it? I tried it on a Debian and it also works. What is your distribution?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 10.04, GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: `==` is wrong within `[ ]` -- it's a bash extension, not supported in POSIX. Use a single `=` to be POSIX compliant... or, if you want to take advantage of bash extensions, use `[[ ]]` instead, but using `[ ]` in a way that _doesn't_ give you POSIX compatibility is just silly.